# Swift: How to check if Error conforms to a protocol

Tags: swift, protocols

Different custom errors & system errors conform to a custom protocol, in this example `LoggableError`.
However, when trying to check the conformance of that `Error` to that custom protocol, Swift fails to cast or even check it (with an `is`-check).
My class receives an Error, but cannot check if the error implements the custom protocol or not.

Example:

```swift
import Foundation

protocol LoggableError: Error {
    var message: String { get }
}

extension URLError: LoggableError {
    var message: String {
        switch code {
        case .notConnectedToInternet: return "no internet"
        default: return ""
        }
    }
}

func log(error: Error) {
    guard let error = error as? LoggableError else { // This cast fails
        return
    }
    print(error.message)
}

let error = URLError(.notConnectedToInternet)
log(error: error)
```

Note that when casting to URLError in that `log(error:)` method, the conformance is checkable & error is cast-able. 
Any ideas here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is caused by the fact that [protocol's don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself).

By changing your `log` method to take its `error` type as a generic parameter rather than an `Error` existential, you can solve the problem, since the generic type now conforms to `LoggableError`, unlike the existential `Error`.

```
func log<E: Error>(error: E) {
  guard let error = error as? LoggableError else {
    return
  }
  print(error.message)
}
```

Or you can use `some Error` as a shorthand instead of having to declare the method generic.

```
func log(error: some Error) {
```

Comment: Off course, Error is a protocol too. ‍♂️
This should be a compiler warning, imo. :)

That one keyword did it! Thanks!

Comment: @JoriDor With Swift 6, it will be a compiler error. You will have to put `any` or `some` in.

Answer (score 2):

You are saying in the declaration of `log(error:)` that the parameter is an `Error` but it will work if you use `some` which makes it an opaque type meaning it will expect some kind of type that conforms to `Error`

```
func log(error: some Error)
```